# can we upload a file or a document in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2010

Hiii,

I am planning on developing a intranet website using access as the database and .net as the front end
or 
A windows application by using access as the both user interface and database

Can anyone tell me, whether we can upload a file or a document into the access database or not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is possible to store a document in an Acces file. The issue is mainly a volume issue. Access databases holding documents tend to grow veeeeeryyyyy fast. People usually prefer to use the database to store a link to a document, rather than the document itself.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the the large files is the overhead that OLE adds when storing in the database. Take a look at this <strike>[MSDN Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103257)</strike> for an example of how to read/write files.

If you want to take a look at the OLE bloating issue look at what [these guys](http://www.ammara.com/articles/imagesaccess.html) have done.